# How to check if I have sudo access?

Tags: linux, sudo, sudoers

I recently got into trouble because of this.

```
$sudo vim /etc/motd 
[sudo] password for bruce: 
bruce is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Is there a way to check if I have sudo access or not?

Comment: @mdpc: Is there another way besides that?

Comment: You have not mentioned if you can attain root access or not.

Comment: This has to be the first instance of [seeing someone following up on "This incident will be reported"](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/incident.png).

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Run `sudo -v`. It is usually used to extend your sudo password timeout, but can be used for determining whether you have any `sudo` privileges.

```
$ sudo -v
Sorry, user [username] may not run sudo on [hostname].
```

Man page excerpt:

> If given the -v (validate) option, sudo will update the user’s time stamp, prompting for the user’s password if necessary.  This extends the sudo timeout for another 5 minutes (or whatever the timeout is set to in sudoers) but does not run a command.

If your user is only allowed to run *specific* commands, this command will work, indicating you are allowed to run *something* with different privileges. While the message looks different when trying to execute a command you're not allowed to in this case (and **no mail is sent to root**), it's still possible you'll get into trouble if the admins read `/var/log/secure`.

```
$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for [username]: 
Sorry, user [username] is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as root on [hostname].
```

To find out *what* you're allowed to run with different privileges, you can use `sudo -l`. Note that this command requires you to enter your password.

Comment: Thanks. sudo -v works for me. The man page says I can run sudo -l as well but that asks for a password. Why is that?

Comment: @Bruce I'm guessing here, but otherwise someone (or a program you run) could find out what programs can be executed (possibly without entering password) by your current user and try to use that information maliciously.

Comment: What do you suppose it means when I get this back: `patrick@<host>:~$ sudo -v sudo: unable to resolve host <host>`? I entered my password and didn't get anything about unauthorized. I know I have `sudo` from successfully running other commands, but that `unable to resolve host` message has me concerned something else might be funky on the host.

Comment: @PatrickM It looks like a problem with the `sudoers` file. In there you can specify on which host a user is authorized to run a specific command (this is useful when using the same `sudoers` file on multiple machines). Possibly the hostname specified in that file could not be resolved. Try checking it with the `host` command for example.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on RHEL 6, `sudo -v` gave "xx is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Comment: @79E09796 Do you know more about your environment? What version of RHEL 6? What version of sudo? I can't find anything in the sources that would explain that, but Red Hat's source RPMs are pretty annoying. Notably, it seems sudo was recently patched quite a bit by Red Hat, so this may be very recent.

Answer (score 65):

This is very simple.  Run `sudo -l`. This will list any sudo privileges you have.

Comment: Maybe downvoted because it repeats what Daniel Beck said nearly two years ago.

Comment: Or explains what happen, it's a comment, at best

Comment: @Jonathan: if u would script in ubuntu rigt now, `sudo -l` asks for a password if u can sudo or not. `sudo -v` asks only if u can, and `"$(whoami)" != "root"` will never ask anything in any linux.

Comment: @bksunday You are correct. I tested now on a clean Debian Jessy and confirmed your results. My previous (deleted now) comment was probably a result of testing on a machine on which I had some `sudo` privs.

Comment: @G-Man but this simple answer helped me more than probably more precise Daniel's answer, where this command is the the very end unfortunatelly...

Answer (score 22):

Gerald Schade's answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1183480/857531), can still be improved!

Use

```bsh
prompt=$(sudo -nv 2>&1)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  # exit code of sudo-command is 0
  echo "has_sudo__pass_set"
elif echo $prompt | grep -q '^sudo:'; then
  echo "has_sudo__needs_pass"
else
  echo "no_sudo"
fi
```

Here's a **complete example of usage in a script**:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

is_root () {
    return $(id -u)
}

has_sudo() {
    local prompt

    prompt=$(sudo -nv 2>&1)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "has_sudo__pass_set"
    elif echo $prompt | grep -q '^sudo:'; then
    echo "has_sudo__needs_pass"
    else
    echo "no_sudo"
    fi
}

elevate_cmd () {
    local cmd=$@

    HAS_SUDO=$(has_sudo)

    case "$HAS_SUDO" in
    has_sudo__pass_set)
        sudo $cmd
        ;;
    has_sudo__needs_pass)
        echo "Please supply sudo password for the following command: sudo $cmd"
        sudo $cmd
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Please supply root password for the following command: su -c \"$cmd\""
        su -c "$cmd"
        ;;
    esac
}

if is_root; then
    echo "Error: need to call this script as a normal user, not as root!"
    exit 1
fi


elevate_cmd which adduser
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is the script-friendly version:

```
timeout 2 sudo id && echo Access granted || echo Access denied
```

since it won't stuck on the password input if you do not have the `sudo` access.

You can also set it in a variable like:

```
timeout 2 sudo id && sudo="true" || sudo="false"
echo "$sudo"
```

<sup>Note: On macOS, you need to install `coreutils`, e.g. `brew install coreutils`.</sup>

Comment: Any alternatives for where `timeout` isn't available by default, e.g. on OS X?

Comment: You need to install `coreutils`, e.g. `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: This does not work for me in a script. For unexplained reason the script hangs until I kill it.

Comment: @beruic you can try this ([explained in my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1591778/1138232)) `timeout -s SIGKILL 5s sudo -v && (echo SUDO Access Granted ; exit 0) || (echo SUDO Access Denied ; exit 1)`

Comment: Please don't do this. `sudo` has the feature you need built-in: `sudo -vn 2> /dev/null && echo you can sudo without password || echo password required or sudo not permitted`

Answer (score 8):

For me, '`sudo -v`' and '`sudo -l`' did not work in a script because sometimes interactive (asking me for a password, like mentioned above). 
'`sudo -n -l`' did also not work, it gave the exit code '1' although I have sudo permissions, because of the missing password.
But extending the command to:

```
A=$(sudo -n -v 2>&1);test -z "$A" || echo $A|grep -q asswor
```

was successful for me for the script.
This expression gives `0` if the current user can call 'sudo' and `1` if not.

Explanation:
The additional parameter `-n` to `sudo` prevents interactivity.
The output `$A` of the command '`sudo -n -v 2>&1`' may be:
 - empty (in this case, sudo can be called by the current user), or:
 - a note that the current user is not authorized for sudo, or:
 - a question text for the password (in this case, the user is authorized).
("asswor" will fit for an english "password" as well as for a German "Passwort").

Comment: This is the best solution

Comment: To make it work for any locale change A to

    A=$(LC_ALL=C sudo -n -v 2>&1)

Answer (score 1):

"Sudo access" comes in flavors.  Two primary flavors:  First you, or a group your a member of, needs to be setup for sudo access in the /etc/sudoers file.

Secondly you need to know your password, or you need to have done a sudo command recently.  Recently enough that the timeout hasn't expired. (Fun fact: you can make the time out very long in your sudoer's file.)

I often want to test for the second kind of access in the prolog of a script that will need to sudo some steps.  When this check fails I can advise the user he needs to enable the 2nd kind of access before running the script.

```
bash-3.2$ if sudo -S -p '' echo -n < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; then echo 'Sudo is enabled.' ; else echo 'Sudo is not enabled' ; fi
Sudo is enabled.
bash-3.2$ sudo -K
bash-3.2$ if sudo -S -p '' echo -n < /dev/null 2> /dev/null ; then echo 'Sudo is enabled.' ; else echo 'Sudo is not enabled' ; fi
Sudo is not enabled
```

The -S tells sudo to read the password from stdin.  The -p sets an empty prompt.  The -K clears the second time of access.

Since it sends stderr to /dev/null, it will also check if the user has the first type of sudo access.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough to tell you if you have root or not:

```
sudo whoami
```

If `sudo` asks for root password, or it does not work, it also means that you don't have root privileges (at least not through `sudo`).

Comment: The OP would need to be on the sudoers list for this to work which defeats the point of the question.

Comment: @Burgi The unsaid part of the answer is that if `sudo` asks for root password, or it does not work, it also means that you don't have root privileges (at least not through `sudo`). I insert it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -nv 2>/dev/null||sudo -v||exit 64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            # Verify if current user is root.
            local current_username=$(whoami)
            [[ "$current_username" == 'root' ]] && echo true && return 0

            # Verify if sudo is installed.
            if [[ $(validate_apt 'sudo') == 'false' ]]; then
                echo false && return 0
            fi

            # Verify if the current user belongs to groups 'sudo' or 'root'.
            local current_user_groups=$(groups $current_username)
            if [[ $current_user_groups == *'root'* ]] ||
                   [[ $current_user_groups == *'sudo'* ]]; then
                echo true && return 0
            fi

            # Verify if file /etc/sudoers.d/username exists.
            if [[ -f /etc/sudoers.d/$current_username ]]; then
                echo true && return 0
            fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to check sudo mode for nice script interactivity/error-checking.

I like Kenorb's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1088918/1138232) which uses timeout, it didn't work for me though because of the default kill signal. So I edited this bit and sprinkled some additions as explained below.

```sh
timeout -s SIGKILL 5s sudo -v && (echo SUDO Access Granted ; exit 0) || (echo SUDO Access Denied ; exit 1)
```

Explanation:

- `-s SIGKILL` specifies `SIGKILL` as a kill signal. I prefer this over `SIGSTOP` since it has less clutter in STDOUT. Full list of kill signals can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317496). Also [SIGSTOP v.s. SIGKILL](https://superuser.com/questions/594508/whats-the-difference-between-sigkill-and-sigstop)

> The signals ***SIGKILL*** and ***SIGSTOP*** cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

- `5s` denotes 5 seconds, seconds is the default but you can also use `m` minutes or `h` hours. For a reference: DURATION parameter description in `man timeout`
- `sudo -v` for reasons specified [in the selected answer](https://superuser.com/a/553939/1138232)
- `exit 0` and `exit 1` to represent success and failure exit status codes respectively. Full list of exit status codes can be found [here 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/892605), [here 2](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html) and [here 3](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bash-exit-status-set-exit-statusin-bash/)
- `;` was used to chain shell commands inline.
- `&&` and `||` are just some boolean expressions that uses `sudo -v` exit code. If you're confused, it's just Boolean/Logical [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

The code below returns a sentence that is better understandable for average user:

```
[ $(fgrep "${USER}" /etc/group | egrep -c ^"(sudo|wheel)\:") -eq 1 ] && echo -e "${USER} has sudo rights" || echo -e "${USER} has not sudo rights"
```

(or there are Linux Distros with other group names for sudo than sudo and wheel ?)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Follow [these](http://rubypond.com/blog/adding-yourself-to-the-sudoers-file) steps to view the sudoers file.  If you're in there, you have sudo.  If not, you can add yourself.

1. `su`
2. `visudo`
3. Bottom of the file, enter `your_username_here ALL=(ALL)       ALL`
4. Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and type `:wq`
5. Type `exit`
6. Re-run your command that needed `sudo`
7. Enter your password (not the root's password)

Comment: The OP "got into trouble" for running `sudo`, so he probably isn't ***the*** system administrator, nor even one of the elite system administrators. He's probably just a user who thought he might have been granted some limited powers. What makes you suspect that he can go `su`?

Comment: Respect for this answer poster, he kept this despite the dislikes so others can benefit from its flawed assumption, and the comment above me.