# What's the difference between SIGKILL and SIGSTOP?

Tags: linux, posix

The manual describes `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` like this:

```
SIGKILL             9    Term    Kill signal
SIGTERM            15    Term    Termination signal
SIGSTOP      17,19,23    Term    Stop the process
```

and states:

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

but what's the difference between the 2 signals?

Comment: Superset question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As is found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals)

`SIGKILL`

> The SIGKILL signal is sent to a process to cause it to terminate immediately. In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal.

`SIGSTOP`

> The SIGSTOP signal instructs the operating system to stop a process for later resumption.

Comment: You might also like to now that SIGINT is a signal that is issued when you press CTRL+C at the terminal. SIGSTOP is NOT a signal that is send when you press CTRL+Z - this one is actually SIGTSTP and contrary to SIGSTOP can by ignored by a process.

Answer (score 37):

`SIGKILL` kills a process and cannot be caught

`SIGTERM` kills a process but can be caught to do a graceful exit

`SIGSTOP` suspends the process until you do a `SIGCONT`

Comment: Was curious when SIGTERM was actually used. `If a process receives SIGTERM, some other process sent that signal.` [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/when-does-the-system-send-a-sigterm-to-a-process)

Answer (score 6):

As the name suggests, `SIGKILL` kill the process instead of `SIGSTOP` which stop the process until the `SIGCONT` be called (to continue the process).