# How To check user configured with root privileges

Tags: linux, privileges

Suppose root user created a user say user1, and made entries in /etc/sudoers file for
"user1" as "user1 ALL=(ALL) ALL".
How can user1 check that he has privileges identical to root user ?
Does it require to create a shell script for it ?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://superuser.com/questions/553932/how-to-check-if-i-have-sudo-access

Answer (score 2):

A user can see what he is allowed to run using `sudo` by running `sudo -ll`. No script is required. Below is an example:

```
$ sudo -ll
Matching Defaults entries for user1 on this host:
    env_reset, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User user1 may run the following commands on this host:

Sudoers entry:
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    RunAsGroups: ALL
    Commands:
    ALL
```

To check if a certain command is allowed you can use `sudo -l command`. If the command is allowed the full path will be printed.

```
$ sudo -l ls
/bin/ls
```

To see what a different user is allowed to do you can add the option `-U username`.

Comment: `sudo -ll` will ask my password, is that correct?

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, of course. It would be a security hazard to reveal such a sensitive information without authenticating the user. ...but if you allow the user to use `sudo` without a password (using the `NOPASSWD:` directive) then `sudo -ll` will not ask for a password.